# Property 'Fund' does not exist on type 'Contract'. Ethersjs ABI typecasting [TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, typescript, solidity, abi, ethers.js

While following Patrick Collins course. I run into a TypeScript issue.

I am using `TypeScript` for this tutorial but the original is in JavaScript.

Below code is causing error.

`index.ts`

```js
 const transactionResp = await contract.Fund({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount) });
```

Error that I get

```bash
error TS2339: Property 'Fund' does not exist on type 'Contract'.
```

The full code of `index.ts`

```js
import { ethers } from "./lib/ethers-5.2.esm.min.js";
import { contractAddress, abi } from "./lib/constants.js";

const fundBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("fundButton") as HTMLButtonElement;

fundBtn.onclick = fund;

async function fund() {
    const amount = "0.2";
    
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
       
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum); 
        const signer = provider.getSigner(); 
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
        try {
            const transactionResp = await contract.Fund({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount) }); 
           //^ Above is Error line [error TS2339: Property 'Fund' does not exist on type 'Contract'.]
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
      
    } else {
        connectBtn.innerHTML = "Install Metamask";
    }
}
```

My `constant.ts` file having ABI definition.

```js
export const contractAddress = "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512";
export const abi = [
    {
        inputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "PriceFeed",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "constructor",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "FundMe__NotOwner",
        type: "error",
    },
    {
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "fallback",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "Fund",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "MINIMUM_USD",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "cheaperWithdraw",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "funder",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        name: "getAddressToAmountFunded",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "index",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "getFunders",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "getOwner",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "getPriceFeed",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "contract AggregatorV3Interface",
                name: "",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "withdraw",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "receive",
    },
];
```

To me it look like its type casting error and hence typescript is not able to read it `Fund` as property. Don't know how to solve it?
May be I need to declare the interface for the ABI? Not sure how to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

`Contract` type that you are using is a general type. If you check the node_modules source code, some of the propertie

```
readonly address: string;
readonly interface: Interface;
readonly signer: Signer;
readonly provider: Provider;
readonly functions: { [ name: string ]: ContractFunction };
readonly callStatic: { [ name: string ]: ContractFunction };
readonly estimateGas: { [ name: string ]: ContractFunction<BigNumber> };
readonly populateTransaction: { [ name: string ]: ContractFunction<PopulatedTransaction> };
readonly filters: { [ name: string ]: (...args: Array<any>) => EventFilter };
```

You need to generate types based on your abi. You can use [ethereum-abi-types-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-abi-types-generator). all you have to do is write a script in `package.json`

```
"genContractType": "abi-types-generator './public/contracts/YourContractName.json' --output='./types' --name=whateverName --provider=ethers_v5",
```

once you run this script and go to "types" directory, you should have `whateverName.ts` file. there will be a lot of types and interfaces in this file but main contract type will be name `YourContractNameContract` type.

Now when you write your contract equation, you can cast it `as YourContractNameContract`